# Как изменить размер drawable animation-list в ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

У меня есть два фрейма 800x600 в оригинале выглядит он так [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0BJb.gif), но я получаю вот это [result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIjTt.png). Как это поправить?
**bulb_anim.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bulb1"
          android:duration="350"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bulb2"
          android:duration="350"/>
</animation-list>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyThemeProgress" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:title">false</item>>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
        <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style><br><br>
```

**activity**

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this,R.style.MyThemeProgress);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Activity);
                dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bulb_anim));
                dialog.show();
```

Comment: Добавьте код разметки, проблема ведь в позиционировании?

Comment: я новичок в этом деле так что не обессудьте, в разметке у меня ничего нету связанного с ProgressDialog это все создается в коде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я все исправил, все что нужно было поменять ProgressDialog на Dialog и стили теперь тоже стали не нужны я просто добавил transparant_color.xml. Мой результат гифка:[image: анимация лампочки]
**transparant_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bulb1"
          android:duration="350"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bulb2"
          android:duration="350"/>
</animation-list>
```

**my_activity.java**

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bulb_anim);
                int width = WRAP_CONTENT;
                int height = WRAP_CONTENT;
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(imageView);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent_color));
                dialog.show();
                animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
                animationDrawable.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы создаете программно, то вы должны указать ширину и высоту программно:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Также можете задать расположение:

```
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // BOTTOM, TOP, LEFT, RIGHT соответственно
```

Для `ProgressBar:`

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyThemeProgress);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bulb_anim));
dialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
dialog.show();`
```

Comment: спасибо за полезную информацию, но drawable все равно остается в маленьком разрешение http://i.piccy.info/i9/e33716b1fc8c4596f5aae44acb0cb216/1500368439/87206/1163052/123.png

Comment: А если заменить `WRAP_CONTENT` на `MATCH_PARENT`?

Comment: нет ничего, все по старому

Comment: Отредактировал, попробуйте

Comment: увы ничего, я облазил все что можно и ничего не нашел решил по этому сюда написать